# Angular ng-options select option visual feedback issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I've got a problem with getting proper visual feedback along with my desired data-binding behaviour. Here's my code:

```
<div ng-app="myTestApp" ng-controller="myTestCtrl">
    <!-- selected value is site.name -->
    <h3>Selected value is site.name property</h3>
    <select ng-model="testSelect" ng-options="site.name as site.name for site in sites track by site.name">
        <option value="">Please choose a site</option>
    </select>
    <div ng-bind="testSelect"></div>

    <hr/>
    <!-- Selected value is site object itself -->
    <h3>Selected value is the site object itself</h3>
    <select ng-model="testSelectTwo" ng-options="site.name for site in sites track by site.name">
        <option value="">Please choose a site</option>
    </select>
    <div ng-bind="testSelectTwo"></div>
</div>
```

And here's the accompanying angular javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myTestApp', []);

app.controller('myTestCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.sites = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Site 1', link: 'http://url'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Site 2', link: 'http://url'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Site 3', link: 'http://url'}
    ];
}]);
```

And here's the jsFiddle of all of the above: http://jsfiddle.net/aZwLY/

Now what I want is for the ng-model to be given the site.name property for my use (top half of jsFiddle example utilizing the above code), but I also want the visual feedback of the actual select changing (bottom half of jsFiddle example).

I haven't been able to think of a solution so far.

Comment: I don't understand what the goal is here. Can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: @JamesKleeh Sure. For example, I want to be able to select Site 1 (which is site.name for the first site object in sites) from the dropdown. I want the ng-model to contain the site.name property. But the problem is that if I have it bind like that, the actual select dropdown does not give me any visual feedback of my selection. The ng-model changes just fine, but again there is no visual feedback. Compare this to when the ng-model is given the whole site object itself (in the bottom half of the JSFiddle).

Comment: What do you mean by "visual feedback"?

Comment: The select dropdown shows my selection. In the top half it stays as "Please choose a site" despite my selection. Ng-model is bound to site.name as I want, but there is no visual feedback (i.e. it still says "Please choose..."). In the bottom half, it changes (the visual feedback I want), but only because it's the whole object itself passed to ng-model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `track by` clause. That is what is causing the problem

Track by is when you have possibly different objects that should be treated as equals. To use your second example, if I did the following:

`$scope.site = {id: 1, name: "Site 3", link: ""};`

It would make the site with id of 3 selected. This is because we are *tracking by* the name.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n7U6V/

Comment: Ah okay. Wow I spent a lot of time thinking about how much of a headache this is and it was because of track by. Thanks a bunch!